# Как лучше всего искать информацию для разработки Android приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, документация, поиск-библиотек

Несколько месяцев занимаюсь разработкой Android приложений в Androd Studio. Главная проблема заключается в поиске информации. К тому времени, как я найду что-то более менее подходящее, за спиной у меня уже будет 10-15 статей, с совершенно кривым объяснением вопроса и таким же кривым кодом.
Сейчас решил попробовать опираться в основном на документацию, в связи с этим вопрос, можно ли считать документацию универсальным средством для поиска ответов на все вопросы или всё таки необходимо использовать и другие источники тоже?

Comment: вы можете использовать любые источники, которые помогут вам решить проблему. оценить качество решения вы сможете только повышая собственную квалификацию (читая профильную литературу) и с опытом, несколько месяцев это вообще не срок. Документация естественно первый источник поиска решений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу дать несколько советов:

1. Книги. Книги читать долго, очень часто они устаревшие (особенно русские переводы), но в них есть несколько плюсов:

   - тему которая рассмотрена в книге, зачастую разобрана очень и очень хорошо, что дает вам возможность понять ее более глубоко.
   - люди которые пишут книгу, зачастую люди с огромным опытом. Книгу всегда перед выпуском читает много других опытных программистов. В статьях же дейстивительно необходимо фильтровать информацию (а когда ты новичек это трудно).

   К тому же надо понимать что, есть практики которые устарели, а есть практики которые используются годами. В этом случае книга - ваш лучший друг.
2. Статьи. Конечно и без них никуда. Хорошо брать какую-то одну тему, по которой вы в данный момент занимаетесь и читать о ней из разных источников. Люди разные, пишут по разному и по разному понимают ту или иную тему, что даст вам возможность получить более широкие взгляды. Статьи позволяют получать более актуальную информацию, но нужно фильтровать.
3. Кодлабы https://codelabs.developers.google.com/ - Очень крутой ресурс от Google где можно найти практические курсы по самым разным темам.
4. Курсы, такие как Udacity, Udemy и др. Так же рекомендую посмотреть на такой ресурс как https://startandroid.ru/ru/ Человек которые его создал начинал это делать еще очень давно и там можно найти много информации устаревшей, но большинство того что там есть основано на документации гугл и работает по сей день практически без изменений.
5. Митапы, конференции. Если вы живете где-то далеко от столицы то смотрите записи. Ну и вообще на YouTube огромное количество крутых лекций по разным темам.
6. Еще не брезгуйте искать прямо на Git. Прям вбиваете название интересующей вас темы и очень часто можно найти пак пет проектов ребят которые что-то делали по этой теме. Там можно найти очень неплохие решения и примеры кода.
7. Ну и конечно же куда без документации. Но лично мне она очень часто не дает понимания темы. Документация это немного не про то (хотя тут многие могут меня захейтить). Документация это как техническая характеристика, ты видишь класс, видишь что в нем есть, но если ты ничерта не понимаешь в теме, то толку от этого мало. А те примеры которые там есть они зачастую такие маленькие, что не дают именно разобраться в теме. Но если это какой-то простой кейс, то да, welcome.

Старайтесь использовать максимально разные, но в то же время комфортные вам источники информации. Иногда чтоб понять одну тему достаточно прочесть 2 статьи, а порой приходится перелопатить весь интернет, прочесть 2 книги и в догонку посмотреть 2 часа видео.

Если можете найти ментора, то это самое крутое, что может быть. Но это не самое простое=)